# How to symbolically integrate 2D exponential function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

Is it possible to symbolically solve a 2D integral of the following form
$$\int d \vec{r}e^{-\frac{\left| \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \right|^2}{2c}}e^{-i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} $$
where $\vec{r} = (x,y)$ and $\left| \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \right|^2 = (x-x')^2 + (y- y')^2$ ?

Comment: Please include in your question the code you are attempting to use to solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is a straightforward application of `Integrate`.

```
Integrate[Exp[-((x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2)/(2 c) - I (kx x + ky y)], 
    {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> c > 0]
(* 2 c E^(-(1/2) c (kx^2 + ky^2) - I (kx x0 + ky y0)) π *)
```